# Чаты на вебсокетах

Tags: python, websokets

Можно узнать, почему, например, вконтакте в личных сообщениях не использует в переписках `WebSockets`, а использует `long polling`? Может кол-во `socket`-соеденений имеет какие-то ограничения? Какие вообще минусы у сокетов? И как обеспечить в случаях с сокетами безопасность, чтобы другие люди не смогли подсоединится к чужому чату (диалогу)?

Comment: Я думаю просто потому, что VK старается работать везде, а старые браузеры не поддерживают WebSocket. Вот и решили одним способом везде. А так хоть постоянно открытое, хоть websocket - это просто 1 tcp коннект, особой разницы нет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю, почему ВКонтакте не использует `WebSocket`, это вопрос к Контакту, но на вопрос безопасности ответить можно.

Подсоединиться к чужому диалогу на `WebSocket`, да и на сокетах вообще, технически почти невозможно. `WebSocket` - это постоянно открытое соединение, работающее на основе `TCP/IP`, а в `TCP/IP` соединение жёстко привязывается к паре `[адрес_клиента:порт_клиента, адрес_сервера:порт_сервера]`. Таким образом, чтобы нелегально подсоединиться к существующему соединению, необходимо каким-то образом "подсунуть" серверу свои данные и получить от него ответ. Это сделать достаточно сложно. В общем случае это возможно только на промежуточном оборудовании, например, на стороне провайдера или на взломанном домашнем роутере. Если же использовать `WebSocket over SSL` (`wss://`), то и метод перехвата трафика становится почти бессмысленным, поскольку ключ шифрования перехватывающей стороне неизвестен. Можно провести атаку типа `MITM`, подменив сертификат сервера, но клиент может не принять сертификат, да и трудоёмкость намного выше.

В общем, при желании спецслужбы и интернет-провайдеры смогут подключиться к вашему веб-сокету, но если они конкретно вас не разрабатывают и вы не в Китае (*Да здравствует Великий Китайский Файрволл!!!*) об этом можно не беспокоиться.